# How can I simplify $5^{\log_3 n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> How can I simplify this expression?
>   $$5^{\log_3 n}$$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Yc4.png))

Ideally, I need something centered on $n$.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried? See how to ask a good question here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1):

This is $5^{\ln n/\ln 3}=e^{\ln n\ln 5/\ln 3}=n^{\ln 5/\ln 3}=n^{\log_35}$.